# Positioning A Circle In The Middle Of Two Divs

Tags: html, css

I have one DIV positioned right.

```
.right {
width:25%;
height:100%;
background-color:#000;
position:fixed;
right:0px;
z-index:1;
```

And left

```
.left {
width:25%;
height:100%;
background-color:#000;
position:fixed;
left:0px;
z-index:1;
```

And I'm trying to put this circle

```
.circle {
height:100px;
width:100px;
border-radius:50px;
background-color:#F00;
position:fixed;
left:45%;
z-index:99;
```

in the middle

this is my HTML

```
<div class="left">
</div>

<div class="centerc">
<div class="circle">
</div>

<div class="right">
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Where did centerc come from? Why doesn't it have a closing tag? Does centerc have any styling?

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you provided?

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this inside `.circle` styling:

```
left:50%;
margin-left:-50px;
```

`left:50%;` will put the left side of the `.circle` in the middle of the screen, then `margin-left:-50px;` will put the `.circle` 50px to the left (half of its width).

Also, it's a good idea to remove the non-closed `.centerc` div.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V5QhF/1/)

```css
*{margin:0;}
body{
    background:#fff;
}
.left{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    left:0;
    background:#222;
}
.circle{
    z-index:1;
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    left:50%; /* Left side of the circle centered */
    margin-left:-50px; /* A half of circle width to the left */
    border-radius:50px;
    background:#F33;
}
.right{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    right:0;
    background:#222;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be working. However, the circle is off-center.

I suggest that you define the circle's position as 50% of the container's width minus 50% of the circle's width:

```
.circle {
    ...
    width:100px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
}
```

Also, since everything is `position:fixed`, I don't see the purpose of `div.centerc`. I removed it.

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

[Working example (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/H79uj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are meaning to have the left and right divs aligned and the circle div floating over them in dead center here's a quick fiddle to set you in that direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/zLsbE/

I added a container div wrapped around all three  (left, right and circle) and set it to `position: relative`

I then set the circle div to `position: absolute` and played with it's left and top alignment to center it.

Note - It's not a responsive solution.

```css
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #000;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #555;
}
.circle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #F00;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/R8YRh/1/ demonstrates using:

```
.centerc {
    text-align:center;
}
```

and the addition of `display: inline-block;` to `.circle`. This required the addition of `top: 0;` to `.right`.

```css
.left {
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
.right {
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top: 0;
    z-index:1;
}
.centerc {
    text-align:center;
}
.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background-color:#F00;
    z-index:99;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="centerc">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="right"></div>
```